# Azure Web Site CPU High at random intervals of the day

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have a Azure Web Site running for 6 months and on Friday 1st April 2016 at 09:50pm the CPU was very high and this had a impact on the performance of the web site. Stopping and restarting the web service solved the problem but it came back at 13:00pm. Since then the CPU has stayed high and making the web site un-useable

I've tried all monitoring tools, Daas, Event Logs, checked for Open Connections and ensure my software is closing or disposing objects correctly.

But the CPU is still high. Only way to resolve is to restart the web service but I dont want to keep doing this.

Has anyone else experience a similar problem and what was the solutions.

The only thing from the event logs that look an issues is the odd "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server", which could be because the SQL Aure is not available.

Please help

Comment: Is the code piece that talks to the sql db fault tolerant ? have u used any retry logic ? if there was some error while connecting to db using retry logic lets u try a few times and see if it works. or finally write a log of the error and move on.

Comment: What process is running? Do you have jobs running on the server. Are there long running requests?

Comment: Hi Aravind, We dont have DB Fault Tolerant. Would you feel this would prevent the High CPU if we handled the Un-Successfully Database Connections

Comment: Hi Peter, We only have one process that runs at 8am in the Morning and this takes about 30 seconds to run. It has been running for the last 6 months. So I dont think it's related to this Job.

Comment: Now we have a HTTP Erro 503: The Service is unavailable. I've had to restart the Azure Web Service !!!

Comment: Hi Aravind, How do I use vb.net to check for sql db fault tolerant and rety logic ??

Comment: Do you have any web jobs running on your site?

Comment: maybe the connection to your sql db has got slower in your data center? try increasing the connect timeout in your connection strings: connect timeout=120

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, high cpu means that your web site is executing code, perhaps a wrong loop on some not frequent code path.

The brute force way to identify what code is being executed, would be to add tracing to your solution by System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("I am here") and then check the Azure Application Log.

Another way would be to attach the Visual Studio Debugger during high cpu and check what is being executed

The other way would be to take a dump or minidump from kudu site and analyze it with WinDbg:
1)What thread is conuming cpu:
!runaway 
2) What is this thread doing:
!clrstack

hth,
Aldo